# Best practices for versioning Hudson settings

Tags: continuous-integration, installation, hudson

We're using Hudson continuous integration server frequently on projects. But Hudson seems lacking of proper versioning of the jobs configuration.

A few times, this has lead to problems: Somebody changes or tweaks the configuration on jobs and something that used to work stopped working.

I have tried to version-control jobs on my local Hudson server (on my laptop). But this is not optimal: 1) it's only for me. 2) i need to mirror jobs from a central build server – and may also need to modify them to work locally. 3) It's pretty cumbersome to setup .gitignores for files to ignore.

As far as I know, there is no way in Hudson to view change history of jobs, and no plugin does it either.

Also, there seems to be no way to export/import settings.

So the question is: How do you keep track of changes? Both in jobs and in general setup of Hudson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Which part of HUDSON_HOME should I put under source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606496/which-part-of-hudsonhome-should-i-put-under-source-control)

The [Audit Trail plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Audit+Trail+Plugin) might be useful to you too if people are breaking configurations and you're having trouble tracking it down.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I gave it a quick look, and it will probably fit my needs. (although I wonder why it isn't part of hudson-core itself)

Comment: I am currently trying out the Audit Trail plugin to see it's abilities. Unless a better answer shows up within the next few days, I am likely to accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option that I just found:
[JobConfigHistory](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JobConfigHistory+Plugin)

Comment: That plugin could also be the perfect jumping off point for SCM integration or similar for versioning these based on hitting the submit button.